# Using vlookup incombination with Match

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Excel worksheet that contains K values for a Watson-Williams 2 sample test - circular statistics. I am using the following formula to lookup the correction K values based upon a `vlookup` and `match` parameters as follows

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(J29,4),'K Correction Factor'!A2:K101,MATCH(MID(J29,5,1),'KCorrection Factor'!A1:K1,0),FALSE)
```

The `LEFT(J29,4)` and `MID(J29,5,1)` formulas extract the row and column values used to look up the correction values from the worksheet. For example take the value 0.9425; `LEFT(J29,4) = 0.94` and `MID(J29,5,1) = 2`. So the long formula should look down the first column to row 0.94 then across to column 2 and return the k value.

When I "evaluate" the formula everything appear to have the right reference but the formula returns a `#N/A`. I've performed this type of `vlookup` and `match` formula before so I know it works, or will work. But something is wrong and I can't figure it out. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - just add `value()` to the formula...

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(LEFT(J29,4)),'K Correction Factor'!A2:K101,MATCH(VALUE(MID(J29,5,1)),'K Correction Factor'!A1:K1,0),FALSE)
```